# XML3D: generateRay

Tags: javascript, xml3d

I'm implementing draggable object in XML3D and i need a help with `xml3d.generateRay` function, as an argument it takes two numbers, as I understand correctly those are x,y coordinates of point in projection space that ray passes through. But are those coordinates in reference to the window element (left-top corner of the browser window) or to the xml upper-left corner?

Second question: how can I get hit point from `getElementByRay`

Specification says differently for different versions - and since there is no spec for 4.9 I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates are given in window space, so relative to the top left corner of the window.

You can get the hit point and hit normal from `getElementByRay` by passing two `XML3DVec3` objects into the function, eg:

```
var hitPoint = new XML3DVec3();
var hitNormal = new XML3DVec3();
xml3dElement.getElementByRay(ray, hitPoint, hitNormal);
```

The function will fill the vectors with the hit point and normal in world space.